# Early ending of code

Tags: html, go

In my code the code is executed before doing all tasks. Whattä do I have to change on my code such that does all tasks before ending?

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"math/rand"
"time"
)

// run x tasks at random intervals
// - a task is a goroutine that runs for 2 seconds.
// - a task runs concurrently to other task
// - the interval between task is between 0 and 2 seconds

func main() {
// set x to the number of tasks
x := 4
// random numbers generation initialization
random := rand.New(rand.NewSource(1234))

for num := 0; num < x; num++ {
    // sleep for a random amount of milliseconds             before starting a new task
    duration := time.Millisecond *                 time.Duration(random.Intn(2000))
    time.Sleep(duration)

    // run a task
    go func() {
        // this is the work, expressed by sleeping for 2          seconds
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println("task done")
    }()
}
}
```

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/fcb8ijB7qj

Comment: Please start with [the tutorial](https://tour.golang.org) and then a [good book](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Books). I appreciate your intent to learn Go, but you should really get certain basics laid in your head first.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as @Laney mentions this can be done using both Waitgroups and channels. Refer code below.

Waitgroups:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

// run x tasks at random intervals
// - a task is a goroutine that runs for 2 seconds.
// - a task runs concurrently to other task
// - the interval between task is between 0 and 2 seconds

func main() {
    // set x to the number of tasks
    x := 4
    // random numbers generation initialization
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    random := rand.New(rand.NewSource(1234))

    for num := 0; num < x; num++ {
        // sleep for a random amount of milliseconds             before starting a new task
        duration := time.Millisecond * time.Duration(random.Intn(2000))
        time.Sleep(duration)
        //
        wg.Add(1)
        // run a task
        go func() {
            // this is the work, expressed by sleeping for 2 seconds
            time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
            fmt.Println("task done")
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("All tasks done")
}
```

Output:

```
task done
task done
task done
task done
All tasks done
```

On playground : https://play.golang.org/p/V-olyX9Qm8

Using channels:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

// run x tasks at random intervals
// - a task is a goroutine that runs for 2 seconds.
// - a task runs concurrently to other task
// - the interval between task is between 0 and 2 seconds

func main() {
    //Channel to indicate completion of a task, can be helpful in sending a result value also
    results := make(chan int)
    // set x to the number of tasks
    x := 4
    t := 0 //task tracker
    // random numbers generation initialization
    random := rand.New(rand.NewSource(1234))

    for num := 0; num < x; num++ {
        // sleep for a random amount of milliseconds             before starting a new task
        duration := time.Millisecond * time.Duration(random.Intn(2000))
        time.Sleep(duration)
        //

        // run a task
        go func() {
            // this is the work, expressed by sleeping for 2 seconds
            time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
            fmt.Println("task done")
            results <- 1 //may be something possibly relevant to the task

        }()
    }
    //Iterate over the channel till the number of tasks
    for result := range results {
        fmt.Println("Got result", result)
        t++
        if t == x {
            close(results)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("All tasks done")
}
```

Output:

```
task done
task done
Got result 1
Got result 1
task done
Got result 1
task done
Got result 1
All tasks done
```

Playground : https://play.golang.org/p/yAFdDj5nhb

Answer (score 1):

In Go, as most languages, the process will exit when the entrypoint `main()` function exits.

Because you're spawning a number of goroutines, the main function is ending before the goroutines are all done, causing the process to exit and not finish those goroutines.

As others have suggested, you want to block your `main()` function until all the goroutines are done, and a couple of the most common ways to do that are either using semaphores ([`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#example_WaitGroup)), or channels ([go by example](https://gobyexample.com/channel-synchronization))

Answer (score 0):

There are many options. For example, you can use channels or [sync.WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#example_WaitGroup)

Answer (score 0):

The program ends when main goroutine ends.
You may use:

- waitgroup - it gives very convenient way to wait when all tasks are done
- channels - read from channel is blocked until new data arrives or channel gets closed.
- naïve sleep - good only for example purposes